# Repeated call to webkitNotifications.requestPermission() doesn't show permission request in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, notifications

Is it possible to request permission for showing desktop notifications in chrome when user has already denied it ? I don't want to spam user with repeated requests. I have accidentaly clicked the "Deny" button and now every time I try to request permission, nothing shows up. Restart of the browser doesn't help either.

This same thing could happen to user. I've searched but didn't find anything in the Settings or in Developer's tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I've finally found answer to my question. Chrome keeps blocking repeated permission requests once the permission was denied in the first place.

However, there is possibility to change the permission manually in settings, but it's very hidden :-). You go to Wrench -> Settings -> Under the Hood -> Content settings -> Notifications -> Manage exceptions -> and there is a list of permissions (both denied and allowed) and you can change them as you like.

Comment: One quick interesting note - if you have installed both regular Chrome (stable, beta, dev) and also Chrome Canary build - the permissions are shared. So if you make changes in one build, it automatically appears in the other build.